# How can I convert input from JTextField into double. Input value is from user

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, parseint

I'm trying to use an input from JTextField and turn it into double 'coz I'm gonna use the input in a mathematical formula in my program.. but when I try to run the codes, it gives an error.. I think I got the wrong way of parsing.. ANY HELP? Thanks!

```
    xLabel = new JLabel("Subject");
    xTF = new JTextField(4);
    xTF.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
    xString = xTF.getText();
    xDouble = Double.parseDouble(xString);
```

Comment: Your code example suggests a possible misunderstanding of how Swing (and GUI environments generally) work, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: What type of string you are entering in text field , does it contain numbers only like 12345 or 12ASDA , are u getting java.lang.NumberFormatException

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `KeyListener` on text components, use a `DocumentFilter`, take a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details
2. You could use a `InputVerifier` instead. See [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details
3. You could use a `JFormmattedField` or `JSpinner` instead.  See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details

It's difficult to tell, but remember, you're operating in an event driven environment, until the user does something, you should not be trying to get the value of a field

Answer (score 0):

Remove any whitespace available by using trim() on the string

```
   xDouble =  Double.parseDouble(xString.trim());
```

Where i'm assuming xString is a valid String and xDouble  is of type Double

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseDouble(String s)` and exception which is related is `NumberFormatException`

> The **java.lang.Double.parseDouble()** method returns a new double
>   initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as done
>   by the valueOf method of class Double.

For example:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str = "50.00001";
     double retval =Double.parseDouble(str);
     System.out.println("Value = " + retval);
   }
}
```

1. [how to convert String to Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))
2. [Source for sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.lang/Double/Java_Double_parseDouble_String_s_.htm)
3. [Source for Paragraph](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm)

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine, did you type in the right values in your textfield before you tested it? Per example if you leave it empty or type in "1,3" it wouldn't probably accept it.

Edited: I just did a test and as I said, it only accepts values like this: "1.3"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MyApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField textField;
JLabel label;
JButton okButton;

public MyApp() {
    textField = new JTextField(4);
    label = new JLabel("N/A");
    okButton = new JButton("Ok");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    okButton.addActionListener(this);


    pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyApp app = new MyApp();

    app.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == okButton) {
        double d = 0;
        d = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
        label.setText(String.valueOf(d));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Just friendly advice, I know you do jot have enough reputation but this is not an answer.

Comment: My goal is to help not get some stupid points. and I just did a test to make sure what I said was right..

Comment: I did not mean to make you upset, and please do not take personal. I just pointed out a rule of this website, yet if you think this is an answer, it is fine with me. You can add more info and format your post, so you can have better chance to get voted up good luck :)

Comment: you forgot your to format your last } . some people are loving to vote down and I love being polite :)

Comment: Yep, fixed it. I hope 'we' helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm gonna try changing my listener. It appears that it's the error. I'm a new-bee and I still have a lot of learning to do. :)

Comment: You're welcome chrisia, make sure you mark the right answer as accepted. To do that, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.