# Fix so that the display can show both decimal numbers and integers java

Tags: java, swing, integer, double

I'm quite new to programming and I am trying to make a calculator. I'm doing this in JFrame and I want to be able to make my display, when I start the program, to be able to show either with decimal point numbers or integer numbers, depends on the calculation.

Like example, 5/2 = 2.5 (not 2), and 4/2 = 2 (not 2.0) or 3 + 4 = 7 (not 7.0). It should be able to do both depending on result. Would appreciate your help, thanks.

```
public void arithmetic_operation () {        
    switch (calculation) {
        case 1: 
            ans = num + Double.parseDouble(txfText.getText());
            txfText.setText(Double.toString(ans));
            break;
        case 2: 
            ans = num - Double.parseDouble(txfText.getText());
            txfText.setText(Double.toString(ans));
            break;
        case 3: 
            ans = num * Double.parseDouble(txfText.getText());
            txfText.setText(Double.toString(ans));
            break;
        case 4: 
            ans = num / Double.parseDouble(txfText.getText());
            txfText.setText(Double.toString(ans));
            break;
    }
}

private void btnDivisionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    num = Double.parseDouble(txfText.getText());
    calculation = 4;
    txfText.setText("");
    lblRes.setText(num + "/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `DecimalFormat`, `NumberFormatter` and `JFormattedTextField`.

Your code could look something like this:

```
String formatPattern = "####.##"
NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter( new DecimalFormat( formatPattern ) );
formatter.setValueClass( Double.class );
DefaultFormatterFactory formatterFactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory( numberFormatter );
JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
```

Take special note of the `formatPattern` parameter. This defines what pattern is applied when formatting your string. This specific pattern will show up to four digits in front of the decimal point and up to two digits behind the decimal point. Remaining zeroes will be cut off, *i.e.* this translates as follows:

- `3.14` --> `3.14`
- `3.14159` --> `3.14`
- `3.0` --> `3`

Also note that the `.` in this pattern is not a literal dot, but rather a decimal separator that is dependent on locale.

In case you want to define your own patterns, take a look at the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

---

You now have all the necessary tools. Go forth and use them to put the solution together.

Comment: How do I implement this into my current code? I don't understand, I need my math equation to be able to take double number from the display then put it out as a string with or without decimal points, depends on calculation. It just says it cannot be converted to double, or it cannot be converted to string.

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615754/how-can-i-convert-input-from-jtextfield-into-double-input-value-is-from-user 2) Then put the result of your equation into the `JFormattedTextField` to display it according to your wishes.

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem that it cannot be converted and when I press my = button I get an error, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet. and still not the result I want.

Comment: So google what that means and how to fix it. This is what us developers do. Both of the answers you got basically give you different versions of a full solution. I have zero interest in debugging your code step by step and providing individualized tutoring.

Comment: To me it seems as if you would benefit from going through some tutorials, so look at the examples here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html or here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Swing/0840__Java_Swing_JFormattedTextField.htm and make an effort to *understand* what is going on there.

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing that, not finding any answers, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Usually i am doing something like this:

```
//supposed the ans is 2.50 
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("2.50");  
System.out.println(number.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

See more : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_striptrailingzeros.htm